# How can I sanitize user-input data to be inserted into my Carto Table?

Tags: javascript, user-input, cartodb

I have an application that inserts user-supplied geographic data and a user-input comment into a Carto table. The [Carto SQL API](https://carto.com/developers/sql-api/reference/#operation/postSQLStatement) works by passing a fully-formed PostgreSQL query via the `q` parameter. **How can I construct the query string in javascript to be passed to the API via a POST call so that single-quotes won't break my query?**

Currently I'm doing something like

```
var sql = "SELECT insert_data('" + user_input +"');";
$.ajax({type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://' + config.cartoUsername + '.carto.com/api/v2/sql', //Sending the data to Carto
        crossDomain: true,
        data: {"q": sql},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            console.log("Data saved");
                        },
        error: function(responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log("Problem saving the data");
                        }
                    });
```

If I submit something like `I'm here` then I get a 400 error

```
{"error":["syntax error at or near \"m\""]}
```

Because the query looks like:

```
SELECT insert_data('I'm here');
```

Are there handy front-end javascript libraries that would sanitize SQL input like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this format of your `user_input` .

```
var user_input = "I am her";
console.log("SELECT insert_data(" + user_input +");");
```

This query will look like : `SELECT insert_data(I am here);`

Comment: That won't work because the input to the sql function has to be a 'single-quoted string'

Answer (score 0):

Currently my solution is to double up any number of single-quotes using [`string.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [a greedy global REGExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), and use JSON.stringify() to sanitize double-quotes.

```
JSON.stringify(user_input.replace(/'+/g, "''"))
```